# How to model Json array in Java?

Tags: java, json, microsoft-graph-api

I am pretty new to Java.
I want to model this request for a batch request to Microsoft graphAPI.

```
{"requests":[
  {"id":"employeeId","method":"GET","url":"/me/employeeId"},
  {"id":"thumbnailPhoto","method":"GET","url":"/me/photo/$value"}]
}
```

So "requests" is an array of BatchRequest object.

What I have currently:

```
// BatchRequest object
public class BatchRequest
{
  private String id;

  private String method;

  private String url;

  public BatchRequest(String id, String method, String url)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.method = method;
    this.url = url;
  }
  
  // getters and setters below
}
```

```
  private List<BatchRequest> requests;

  @Override
  public UserInfoResponse callGraphApi()
  {
    BatchRequest employeeId = new BatchRequest("employeeId", "GET", "/me/employeeId");
    BatchRequest photo = new BatchRequest("thumbnailPhoto", "GET", "/me/photo/$value");

    requests.add(employeeId);
    requests.add(photo);

    return callGraphApi(requests);
  }
```

Is this how I would model the JSON?

Comment: That's exactly how to do it.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [Jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) while i was trying to figure out how to model my Json response into java objects in android app development. Install **gson** or **jackson** in your project and it'll take care of the things under the hood.

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class BatchRequest {

    @SerializedName("requests")
    @Expose
    private List<Request> requests = null;

    public List<Request> getRequests() {
        return requests;
    }

    public void setRequests(List<Request> requests) {
        this.requests = requests;
    }

}
```

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Request {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("method")
    @Expose
    private String method;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that website is really helpful. I am using Jackson. This is how I am using it in my main method. 1st) I make a new Request object, 2nd) add it to List<Request> requestList. And 3rd) BatchRequest requests=new BatchRequest(requestList).

Answer (score -1):

Sure. The task of turning an instance of a simple java object into a bunch of JSON, as well as the job of turning a bunch of JSON, combined with a list of simple java classes into instances of those classes, is called 'marshalling'. You'll need a library to do it; the popular ones are [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: I am using Dropwizard framework, so I guess Jackson takes care of things under the hood.